# How can I make an anchor tag in a list item function properly when resized for mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have an `<a>` tag in an `<li>` as a button in the header of my application which is responsive. However, when I scroll down to mobile sizes, the `<a>` tag no longer functions.

[Here](http://3dslides.elasticbeanstalk.com/) is a link to the site.

The `<a>` tag that I am referencing is the "Get Started" item. I have no idea why it would stop working on resize. Can anyone help me with this? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set `click` event for it?

Comment: I apologize for the poor choice of wording, this is an `a` tag. I just have it set to a specific route on my server. Here is the line of code... `<li><a href="/create" className="button style1 big">Get Started</a></li>`

Comment: Anyway, this is only `css` thing, so I think only `css` should be tagged :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` property to your button.

Comment: Thanks! this works. Can't believe I overlooked that!